# SMARTY remove array with same value

Tags: php, smarty

I tried to find something similiar but unsuccessfully. I need to remove an array if $color.code duplicate.

Code:

```
foreach $element.modifications as $modification_id => $modification}
    {if $modification != null}
        {foreach $modification.colors as $color}
            <span class="color" style="background:#{$color.code};"></span>
        {/foreach}
    {/if}
{/foreach}
```

When I debug($color) I get arrays:

**Array
(
    [code] => 333333
)**

**Array
(
    [code] => 333333
)**

**Array
(
    [code] => ABDB25
)**

And I need to get only once if code is same. Can someone help me or give any examples how I can do that?

Answer (score 0):

When constructing array make your keys as `code` `$modification['colors'][$color['code']] = $color;`. It will automatically creates unique-key array.

---

Another option is to use `code` pool:

```
$pool = [];
$newColors = [];

foreach ($modification['colors'] as $color) {
    if (!isset($pool[$color['code']])) {
        $newColors[] = $color;
        $pool[$color['code']] = true;
    }
}

$modification['colors'] = $newColors;
```

Comment: @PauliusJasiulis Accept answer if it satisfies you